# Django - sort related items, in a template, by a number of filtered foreign key objects

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have a blog with nested categories.

I am displaying them like so:

```
{% for category in categories %}
   <h1> {{category.title}} </h1>
   {% for subcategory in category.subcategories %}
      <h1> {{subcategory.title}} </h1>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to sort categories and their subcategories by a number of published posts.

How can I do that?

---

Maybe I could use ordering in Meta class in models, but I don't know if it's possible to order by a number of filtered foreign keys. I would also prefer not to do that in models, because I don't want to always sort them in that order.

Or maybe I could write some sort of template tag that would sort related items, and it seems convenient, but I don't know how.

Or maybe there's some other, better way?

---

Update:

I have created a filter that sorts categories by the number of posts:

```
@register.filter
def sortbyposts(categories):
    categories = categories.annotate(number_of_posts=Count('posts')).order_by('-number_of_posts')
    return categories
```

I can use it like so:

```
{% for category in categories|sortbyposts %}
   <h1> {{category.title}} </h1>
   {% for subcategory in category.subcategories|sortbyposts %}
      <h1> {{subcategory.title}} </h1>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But now I need to Count() by filtered posts. Can I do that?

Comment: Why not sort `categories` in the view before passing it to template context?

Comment: Because category.subcategories is returning unsorted subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Create template tag:

```
@register.filter
def sortbypostcount(children):
    children_postcount = []
    for child in children:
        child.postcount = child.posts.filter(published=True,rational=False).count()
        children_postcount.append(child)

    children_postcount.sort(key=lambda x: x.postcount, reverse = True)

    return children_postcount
```

Use it to sort the results:

```
{% for category in categories|sortbypostcount %}
   <h1> {{category.title}} </h1>
   {% for subcategory in category.subcategories|sortbypostcount %}
      <h1> {{subcategory.title}} </h1>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```